# pass System.Func to a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, func

I'd like to pass a function(a) to a method(b) as a parameter and than start a new thread that executes this function(a). Similar to:

```
Thread tr = new Thread(()=>SomeMethodWithParams(params))
```

But like:

```
public void SomeMethod(System.Func<string> SomeMethodWithParams)
{ 
   Thread tr = new Thread(SomeMethodWithParams);//how to do this right??
   tr.Start();
}
```

I would like to do this,

```
 public void RunThrededJobs(Action[] actions)
{
    for(int i =0; i<actions.Length; i++)
    {
        ThreadStart x = new ThreadStart(actions[i]);
        Thread someThread = new Thread(x);
        someThread.IsBackground = true;
        someThread.Start();
    }
}
```

but with parameters in a method that is executed in a new Thread.

Comment: `Func<string>` is an action that returns a string. You want an `Action<string>` instead. Something like `SomeMethod(Action<string> SomeMethodWithParams, string param)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can handle this, but I'm a little unclear as to exactly how you need to use it.  But, given your function definition for `RunThrededJobs` you can execute it like this:

```
Action[] actions = {
    () => SomeMethodWithParams("foo"),
    () => SomeMethodWithParams("bar"),
    () => SomeMethodWithParams("baz")
};

RunThrededJobs(actions);
```